problem connecting postgres docker compose
i have a project with 3 services
1-backend for golang project with groom db manager
2-db for postgres sql
3-redis for session manager
i have this dockercompose file
services:
   db:
    image: postgres:15.7
    restart: always
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
    - ./db/table.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
    - '5433:5432'
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: postgres
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
    
   redis:
    image: redis:7.0.12
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - '6380:6379'
   
   backend:
   
    build: ./backend
    network_mode: bridge
   
    
    ports:
       - '8000:8089'  
    depends_on:
      - db

  

when i run docker compose build
and i run docker compose up i get this error on backend service
[error] **failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5433: connect: connection refused)**

my connection string for postgres sql is
connection is :=>postgres://postgres:123@127.0.0.1:5433/postgres?sslmode=disable

and one more thing is 2 other services works properly
and when i run maing.go localy without docker it can connect to db and redis server
i tried change --network=host but not works and stil get that error

postgres is not running on 127.0.0.1; it's running on a host called db. You should use that hostname in your connection string.

But why when i connect from local to db127.0.0.1 it works?

Is this a PostgreSQL problem, a Docker (or Docker Compose) problem, a Go problem, or really one with the YAML file itself?

You are port forwarding contianer port 5432 to host port 5433 on your host, so localhost:5433 is valid on your host, but not from another container. Port forwarding does not impact connections from other containers.

Try changing it to the connection string to
postgres://postgres:123@db:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable

I have replaced 127.0.0.1 with db
the reason is the two containers, you backend container and your database container, are in different universes(imagine each running on different computers) they have different networks config they know nothing about each other so when you tell the backend service that it needs to connect to 127.0.0.1 it thinks I got to connect to port 5432 on my localhost (not your machine localhost), its if each run on a seperate computer
so backend tries to connect to port 5432 on its localhost but it found nothing because the database it running on another container(seperate computer) on port 5432
docker compose solves that by giving you a way to make them communicate even though they are not in the same container(computer), by making you just use the name
in this connection string we are telling docker compose that there is a service you have that I named "db" I want to connect to it, and docker compose dose everything in the background to make sure this happen
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    networks:
      - main
    volumes:
      - ./db/table.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    networks:
      - main
  backend:
    networks:
      - main
    build: ./backend

    ports:
      - "8000:8089"
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  main:


here its good formatted version of your compose file I also added a network main and made them all part of it
see if this work for you :)

thanks but i think this composer file in end of file is incomplete  .i got this error *services must be a mapping*

@Vali This problem mostly means there is a problem with your yaml file indentation, indentation is very important in yaml file , If you are using visual studio code you can install Prettier extention and enable it, the extention would auto format them for you

@Vali I changed the compose file I provided try to either copy paste it into your code editor and try it, or as I said before code formatter would be great

yes its works know and for backend i must user :8000 not 127.0.0.1:8000. why? i dont know but it works.

Your db is not running on 127.0.0.1, it's running on it's own IP address, which you can find out by running docker inspect <container_name>.
First of all, use container_name in docker-compose.yml. Otherwise your db container will have a random name assigned. I said "random" -- usually it has some logic behind it, but you can't rely on the name to be constant.
services:
  db:
    container_name: my_postgres
    ...
  ...

Next, use the container name (my_postgres in my example) in the connection string: postgres://postgres:123@my_postgres:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable 
